# Visual Studio 2012 Architecture Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I can't find anything of the sort, but I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and trying to access the Architecture Explorer. When I select it from the View menu I get a quick (< 1 second) mouse loading icon then nothing happens.

No error, no action.

Same happens when I attempt to generate a dependency graph for the solution, no error message is given.

I'm think I must have missed a step somewhere, is there an add-in that is required for this to work?

I've tried re-downloading and reinstalling twice now but to no avail. Everything else works perfectly.

Comment: anything shown in the output window? What about the event logs?

Comment: I couldn't find it immediately I was expecting it in the main window panel, but found it had actually opened in the bottom right panel, with find/breakpoints.  Also in VS2012 some windows can vanish (test explorer is one that does this) and the only way to get them back is to keep closing files until there is room for them to display.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I have a blank output window and nothing in the Event log - Am i correct in thinking it appears under Application > VSS ?  I have tried closing every open window and still nothing appeard anywhere, as I said it appears to load for a split-second but I get no error or window anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this issue ...

I ran Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (Didn't notice there was an update, still unsure as to why a notification didn't pop up as usual). Anyway, after this install the Architecture Explorer began to work.

Thanks for the input :)