# Architecture Explorer menu missing in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: architecture, visual-studio-2013

In all the videos and screenshots I come across there's an architechture menu at the top, but mine has no such menu. Tried to add it through tools - customize, but didn't see it there. I don't know if it has anything to do with the issue, but C:\Users\ (User)\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\ArchitectureExplorer is empty.

So, how do I get this architecture menu?

Comment: Have you tried what [this person][1] did?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028929/visual-studio-2012-architecture-explorer

Comment: @WankyMcSpanky I have the latest update, but I decided to download it over again and "repair" my Visual Studio. We'll see if that fixes it when it finally finishes.

Comment: @Tyler  what is the edition of your visual studio 2013. If  it is community edition then you will not find. It is available for Enterprise editions see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Editions_feature_grid)

Answer (score 0):

It was available only with Enterprise version. 
Also, they have [removed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/10/24/upcoming-changes-in-visual-studio-architecture-and-design-tools/) it.

Comment: Try explaining your answer. Give examples and sources.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2061480.aspx?missing+Architecture+menu+in+VS+2015), it's available only in Ultimate editions.